# Trigger Jenkins build cli, nested jobs

Tags: jenkins, nested, command-line-interface

I'm struggling with a bit of trouble here. I'm supposed to trigger Jenkins build via Jenkins CLI. While it should be easy in itself, it is not. The trouble is that, my jobs look like following

```
A-
 |
 B-
  |
  C
```

So they are nested. When I give command list all I only receive A as an output. So I can only trigger job A but my task is to trigger job C. How can I do it?

I've tried passing the link of C job as a parameter in Jenkins CLI but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, maybe it will help somebody later on. Instead of passing job as 'a/job/b/job/c' we're supposed to pass it as 'a/b/c'.